# Form.valid is not working in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to validate the all the components of the form using 
`'formName'.valid` in Type Script.

I want to validate the "home form's all the fields" .In here I create the input field  and validate using the validator.
If the form is valid "Home Form is valid" alert should be popped up,if not "Home Form is invalid" should be popped up.

The else part ("Home Form is invalid") is working when the form is invalid. But the if part ("Home Form is valid) is not working the when the form is valid.

I wrote the below code in constructor.

How to solve this problem?

```
if (this.homeForm.valid) {
  alert("Home Form is valid");
}

else {
 alert("Home Form is invalid");
}
```

[**Source Code-StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tr3yx5)

Comment: what is the issue? If you remove the validator from your formcontrol, it correctly alerts that form is valid.

Comment: Can you write the form as well, the question does not seem complete

Comment: I have edited the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an errors in your code there, first of all you did not added **formControlName** and did not properly closed your  tag, so this:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home" <br>`
should be

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="homeName" formControlName="homeName">`

And this will make validation work, another thing is that your constructor alerts are only called once, to fix it you can do following:

in your app.components.ts

```
constructor(private homeFB: FormBuilder) {

    this.homeForm = this.homeFB.group({
      homeName: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
    this.onChanges(); 
  }
  onChanges(): void { 
    this.homeForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
    if (this.homeForm.valid) {
      alert("Home Form is valid");
    } else {
      alert("Home Form is invalid");
    }
    });
  }
```

Hope this will help you out. Here is a link to your [example updated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewpvdb)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to connect the input field to the formcontrol.
So write:

```
<input formControlName="homeName" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Home">
```

inside your form, and you'll be fine.